# Strange error of Hierarchical Clustering in R

Tags: r, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering

My R program is as below:

```
hcluster <- function(dmatrix) {
    imatrix <- NULL
    hc <- hclust(dist(dmatrix), method="average")
    for(h in sort(unique(hc$height))) {
        hc.index <- c(h,as.vector(cutree(hc,h=h)))
        imatrix <- cbind(imatrix, hc.index)
    }
    return(imatrix)
}

dmatrix_file = commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)[1]
print(paste('Reading distance matrix from', dmatrix_file))
dmatrix <- as.matrix(read.csv(dmatrix_file,header=FALSE))

imatrix <- hcluster(dmatrix)
imatrix_file = paste("results",dmatrix_file,sep="-")
print(paste('Wrinting results to', imatrix_file))
write.table(imatrix, file=imatrix_file, sep=",", quote=FALSE, row.names=FALSE, col.names=FALSE)
print('done!')
```

My input is a distance matrix (of course symmetric). When I execute above program with a distance matrix larger than about thousands records(Nothing happen for several hundreds), it gave me the error message:

```
Error in cutree(hc, h = h) : 
  the 'height' component of 'tree' is not sorted
(increasingly); consider applying as.hclust() first
Calls: hcluster -> as.vector -> cutree
Execution halted
```

My machine has about 16GB of RAMs and 4CPU, so it won't be the problem of resources.

Can anyone please let me know what's the problem? Thanks!!

Comment: Naively implemented, hierarchical clustering has `O(n^3)` complexity (in fact, the known `O(n^2)` algorithms are only for some specialized versions, see `SLINK`, `CLINK`). It might indeed by an issue of complexity, although the error doesn't look like this.

Comment: I would like to go deeper, coud you post the sample of dmatrix_file and give directions how to scale up?

Comment: Agree with Peter - can't you make dmatrix_file available, or a dummy dataset of same dimensions?

Answer (score 6):

I'm not much of an R wizard - but I ran into exactly this problem.

A potential answer is described here:

https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2008-May/163409.html

Comment: **TL;DR** hc$height <- round(hc$height, 10)

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the cutree function here
http://code.ohloh.net/file?fid=QM4q0tWQlv2VywAoSr2MfgcNjnA&cid=ki3UJjFJ8jA&s=cutree%20component%20of%20is%20not%20sorted&mp=1&ml=1&me=1&md=1&browser=Default#L1

You may try adding the k scaler for the number of groups, this will override the height argument. If not you may look at what hc$height is because if it is not a numeric, complex, character or logical vector, is.unsorted will return true and give you this error.

```
if(is.null(k)) {
    if(is.unsorted(tree$height))
        stop("the 'height' component of 'tree' is not sorted (increasingly)")
    ## h |--> k
    ## S+6 help(cutree) says k(h) = k(h+), but does k(h-) [continuity]
    ## h < min() should give k = n;
    k <- n+1L - apply(outer(c(tree$height,Inf), h, ">"), 2, which.max)
    if(getOption("verbose")) message("cutree(): k(h) = ", k, domain = NA)
}
```